# “The requested quantity for “xxxxxx” is not available” Only displays when customer goes to a new page…

Tags: magento

Say we only have 1,000 quantity of a product, but a customer adds 5,000, it should display the error message [The requested quantity for “xxxxxx” is not available] immediately after the try to add the 5,000 quantity. However, on a site we’re building, it doesn’t display this error message until after they click on a new page.

Here is a link to the site where it’s happening: http://partytimebr.com/natures-imprint-7-round-dinner-plate.html

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` on the template where you want the message block to appear. In the base template, it is in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`. Make sure to bring it over to your template. (see line 39 [here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml))